# A Variational Calculus Question, Newtons Equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, optimal-transport

Lets work in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and ignore extensions to manifolds for now. Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

From classical physics, in the absence of a potential, the action $\mathcal{A}$ is the integral over time of the kinetic energy:

$$
\mathcal{A}(\gamma)=\int_0^1\frac{\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\|^2}{2} dt.
$$

Minimising this action over 'admissible curves' starting at $\gamma(0)=x$ ending at $\gamma(1)=y$ we get

$$
c(x,y):=\frac{\|x-y\|^2}{2}=\inf\big\{ \mathcal{A}(\gamma),~\gamma(0)=x,~\gamma(1)=y,~"\gamma~\text{admissible}" \big\}.~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$

The squared distance $\|x-y\|^2$ is used as the cost in the Wasserstein distance (an optimal transport problem).

I interpret this as the cost of a particle moving through Euclidean space at the absence of friction is determined just by the distance between the points.

If there is friction i.e a particle  follows Newtons Equation
\begin{align}
    \frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}=&\dot{\gamma}(t)~~~~~~~~~(2)
    \nonumber
    \\
    \frac{d\dot{\gamma}(t)}{dt}=&-\nabla V(\gamma(t)).
    \\
   t\in[0,1],&~ \gamma_0=x,\gamma_1=y
\end{align}

where $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is some potential. The associated action (i.e $(2)$ is the Euler Lagrange equation : ) is

$$ 
\mathcal{A}(\gamma)=\int_0^1  \frac{\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\|^2}{2}-V(\gamma(t)) dt.
$$

$\textbf{Can I associate a cost function to the above, like we have in equation $(1)$?}$, and how can I interpret this cost $c(x,y)$!?